# How to scrape each td tag content using Python 3

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The content that I want to analyze is as shown below:

```
<tr>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">1470-160X</td>

<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;"><a href="http://www.letpub.com.cn/index.php?journalid=2408&amp;page=journalapp&amp;view=detail" style="color:#0099FF; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank">ECOLOGICAL INDICATORS</a><br><br><font color="grey">ECOL INDIC</font></br></br></td>

<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">3.190</td>

<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">2区</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">环境科学与生态学</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">环境科学</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">SCIE</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">No</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">容易</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">约3.0个月</td>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;"><a href="http://www.letpub.com.cn/index.php?page=journalapp&amp;view=detail&amp;journalid=2408&amp;xuanxiangk_id=2#xuanxk_3" style="color:#0099FF; text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank">文章</a>
<td style="border:1px #DDD solid; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left; padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;">33977</td></td>

</tr>
```

You can also see the screenshot (A demo):

[image: So, what I want to do is do get each td's] content and add it to the corresponding list.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
journal_ISSN = []
journal_name = []
journal_affecting_factors = []
journal_JCR_zone = []
journal_parent_class = []
journal_sub_class = []
journal_SCI = []
journal_acception = []
journal_period = []

for i in range(2, 3):
url = "http://www.letpub.com.cn/index.php?page=journalapp&view=search&searchname=&searchissn=&searchfield=&searchimpactlow=&searchimpacthigh=&searchimpacttrend=&searchscitype=&searchcategory1=%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6%E4%B8%8E%E7%94%9F%E6%80%81%E5%AD%A6&searchcategory2=%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6&searchjcrkind=&searchopenaccess=&searchsort=relevance&searchsortorder=desc&currentsearchpage="
resp = urlopen('%s%d%s' % (url, i, 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")


journal_table = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table_yjfx"})
# rows = journal_table.find_All("tr")[1:]
print(journal_table)

for line in journal_table:
    rows = line.findAll('tr')
    for single_line in rows[1:10]:
        col = single_line.findAll('td')
        journal_ISSN.append(col[0].string.strip())
        journal_name.append(col[1].string.strip())
        journal_affecting_factors.append(col[2].string.strip())
        journal_JCR_zone.append(col[3].string.strip())
        journal_parent_class.append(col[4].string.strip())
        journal_sub_class.append(col[5].string.strip())
        journal_SCI.append(col[6].string.strip())
        journal_acception.append(col[7].string.strip())
        journal_period.append(col[8].string.strip())
```

Do not get a way to get it done. Anyone can help?

And I received the error message:

AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `text` instead of `string` and change your for loop, below is full code for your reference:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
journal_ISSN = []
journal_name = []
journal_affecting_factors = []
journal_JCR_zone = []
journal_parent_class = []
journal_sub_class = []
journal_SCI = []
journal_acception = []
journal_period = []
url = "http://www.letpub.com.cn/index.php?page=journalapp&view=search&searchname=&searchissn=&searchfield=&searchimpactlow=&searchimpacthigh=&searchimpacttrend=&searchscitype=&searchcategory1=%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6%E4%B8%8E%E7%94%9F%E6%80%81%E5%AD%A6&searchcategory2=%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6&searchjcrkind=&searchopenaccess=&searchsort=relevance&searchsortorder=desc&currentsearchpage=2"
resp = urlopen(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read().decode('utf-8'), "html.parser") #decode to utf-8
journal_table = soup.find("table", {"class": "table_yjfx"})
rows = journal_table.find_all('tr')[2:-1] #filter to get only table data
for row in rows:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    journal_ISSN.append(col[0].text.strip())
    journal_name.append(col[1].text.strip())
    journal_affecting_factors.append(col[2].text.strip())
    journal_JCR_zone.append(col[3].text.strip())
    journal_parent_class.append(col[4].text.strip())
    journal_sub_class.append(col[5].text.strip())
    journal_SCI.append(col[6].text.strip())
    journal_acception.append(col[7].text.strip())
    journal_period.append(col[8].text.strip())
```

Then you can print `journal_JCR_zone[0]` and `journal_parent_class[0]`

```
print journal_JCR_zone[0]
print journal_parent_class[0]
```

Output:

```
4区
环境科学与生态学
```

Or you can write your result to file like this:

```
with open('chinesechar.txt','wb') as outf:
    outf.write(journal_sub_class[0].encode("utf-8"))
```

The will write `环境科学` to file `chinesechar.txt`

Comment: Thank you friend, but it still did not work. The error message was: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It seemed that the col received only one td a time, so there was not col[1], col[2] etc. what do you think?

Comment: can you please update your current code in the question so that I can help to trouble shooting.

Comment: @VincentYuan you can refer my updated answer with full code, you could expand it for your purpose.

Comment: So good so far. I noted that in URL you replace the Chinese characters with """=%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6%E4%B8%8E%E7%94%9F%E6%80%81%E5%AD%A6""", does it tell Python it is Chinese characters?

Comment: Thank you friend, I wonder why the """.decode("utf-8")""" methond can not help Python translate the Chinese characters into the code that can be processed?

Comment: @VincentYuan I have updated the answer, you can use `resp.read().decode('utf-8')`. For the url, I use the one you asked in the question, and all `%` is URL encoding format, url will translate all other characters to url encoding format. BTW, please mark as accepted answer if it is the solution.

Comment: Great help! Thank you!